# local storage for stopwatch in Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to create a web site and there will be a option that when the user logging it automatically start to count the user working time,

Is it possible that while refreshing the page disable stopwatch is rest automatically,

how can i stable the stopwatch while changing the page

my code given bellow

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="time" class="pointable btn-icon"></a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var startTime;
var timeout;
var pauseTime = 0;
var mils;
var paused = false;
var count = 0;

$('#time').html('00:00:00');
var btn = $(this);
startTime = new Date();
clock();
function clock() {
    //$('#time').removeClass('paused');
    var curTime = new Date();
    mils = (curTime - startTime) + pauseTime;
    var time = milToTime(mils);
    formatTime(time);

    var outStr = time.h + ':' + time.m + ':' + time.s;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = outStr;
    timeout = setTimeout(clock, 20);

}
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});

function formatTime(time) {
    for (var i in time) {
        if (i == "mils") {
            if (time[i] < 1) {
                time[i] = "000";
            } else
                if (time[i] < 10) {
                    time[i] = "00" + time[i];
                } else
                    if (time[i] < 100) {
                        time[i] = "0" + time[i];
                    }
        } else if (time[i] < 10) {
            time[i] = "0" + time[i];
        }
    }
    return time;
}

function milToTime(mil) {
    mi = mil % 1000;
    seconds = parseInt(mil / 1000) % 60;
    minutes = parseInt(mil / 1000 / 60) % 60;
    hours = parseInt(mil / 1000 / 3600);
    return { s: seconds, m: minutes, h: hours, mils: mi };
}

});
```

and [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sw3sojmg/)

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Is cookie option not a problem for you?

Comment: I want to stay the stopwatch counting while refresh the page

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sw3sojmg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have agreed to use cookie though its a bad practice and many users may not have enabled cookies on their browser, I've come up with a code that will help you achieve your requirement.

```
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var startTime;
    var timeout;
    var pauseTime = 0;
    var mils;
    var paused = false;
    var count = 0;

    $('#time').html('00:00:00');
    var btn = $(this);

    if (getCookie("time") != "" && getCookie("time") != "NaN") {
        startTime = getCookie("time");
    } else {
        startTime = Date.now();
        createCookie ("time", startTime);
    }

    clock();

    function clock() {
        var curTime = Date.now();
        mils = (curTime - startTime) + pauseTime;
        var time = milToTime(mils);
        formatTime(time);

        var outStr = time.h + ':' + time.m + ':' + time.s;
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = outStr;

        timeout = setTimeout(clock, 20);
    }
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    });

    function formatTime(time) {
        for (var i in time) {
            if (i == "mils") {
                if (time[i] < 1) {
                    time[i] = "000";
                } else
                    if (time[i] < 10) {
                        time[i] = "00" + time[i];
                    } else
                        if (time[i] < 100) {
                            time[i] = "0" + time[i];
                        }
            } else if (time[i] < 10) {
                time[i] = "0" + time[i];
            }
        }
        return time;
    }

    function milToTime(mil) {
        mi = mil % 1000;
        seconds = parseInt(mil / 1000) % 60;
        minutes = parseInt(mil / 1000 / 60) % 60;
        hours = parseInt(mil / 1000 / 3600);
        return { s: seconds, m: minutes, h: hours, mils: mi };
    }

});
```

Please check this out on **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sw3sojmg/4/)**.

**Edit:** Refresh the entire page and see. It works...!! :) But you would wanna remove the cookie on user logout or rest it on user login. Or else that would be giving you the start time of previous login and it would be and havoc then...!!

Now, if you don't want to go with cookies, then the other options are Session, Query String or Application header key-value information... But then you have to handle all of them on the server end.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Refresh the entire page and see. It works...!! :) But you would wanna remove the cookie on user logout.